# How to modify header for XML target file using PL/SQL?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a procedure that exports data from Oracle table to XML target. Code used is:

```
ctx := DBMS_XMLGEN.newcontext (v_sql_text);
   DBMS_XMLGEN.setnullhandling (ctx, 0);
   DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowsettag (ctx, 'RENTAL_Set');
   DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowtag (ctx, 'RENTAL_Record');
   xmldoc := DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml (ctx);
   DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (xmldoc,
                                'path',
                                v_file_name,
                                0);
   DBMS_XMLGEN.closecontext (ctx);
```

I'm getting the first line in target file as:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>`
I need it to be
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way directly through `dbms_xmlgen`. But you could bounce the generated XML through a BLOB and specify the character set as part of that; instead of:

```
   xmldoc := DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml (ctx);
```

you can do, with an additional XMLType variable and a context switch:

```
declare
...
   xml xmltype;
begin
...
   xml := DBMS_XMLGEN.getxmltype (ctx);
   select xmlserialize(
      content
         xmltype(
            xml.getblobval(nls_charset_id('UTF8')),
            nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
        version '1.0')
   into xmldoc
   from dual;
```

which then gets:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RENTAL_Set>
  <RENTAL_Record>
    ...
  </RENTAL_Record>
</RENTAL_Set>
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d57b19a22eec30fe12756fcc326b740c)

The `xml` value is generated from the same source; it's now just an XMLType instead of a CLOB at this point. That is then converted to a BLOB with character set UTF8 specified. That BLOC is converted back to an XMLType, but now it knows the character set. (It feels like there shoudl be a way to skip some of those steps...) And because it's now a BLOB-based XMLType the encoding is included by XMLSerialize. That generates a CLOB, which you can assign to `xmldoc` - and then carry on with the file write or whatever other processing you need.

Comment: This worked for me but not quite. I am now getting ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>``` in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DBMS_XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlque.htm#ARPLS69992) as:

```
qryCtx := DBMS_XMLQuery.newContext(v_sql_text);

DBMS_XMLQuery.setNullAttributeIndicator(qryCtx, FALSE);
DBMS_XMLQuery.setEncodingTag(qryCtx, 'UTF-8');
DBMS_XMLQuery.setRowsetTag(qryCtx, 'RENTAL_Set');
DBMS_XMLQuery.setRowTag(qryCtx, 'RENTAL_Record');
o_results := DBMS_XMLQuery.getXML(qryCtx);

DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (o_results, 'path', v_file_name, 0);

DBMS_XMLQuery.closeContext(qryCtx);
```

##### [EDIT]

To keep the DBMS_XMLGEN structure use this code block (**credits to @AlexPoole**):

```sql
declare
   ctx dbms_xmlquery.ctxHandle;
   xmldoc clob;
   v_sql_text varchar2(4000) := 'select * from dual';
begin
   ctx := DBMS_XMLQuery.newContext(v_sql_text);

   DBMS_XMLQuery.useNullAttributeIndicator(ctx, FALSE);
   DBMS_XMLQuery.setEncodingTag(ctx, 'UTF-8');
   DBMS_XMLQuery.setRowsetTag(ctx, 'RENTAL_Set');
   DBMS_XMLQuery.setRowTag(ctx, 'RENTAL_Record');
   DBMS_XMLQuery.setRowIDAttrName(ctx, null);

   xmldoc := DBMS_XMLQuery.getXML(ctx);
  -- dbms_output.put_line(xmldoc);
   DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (xmldoc, 'path', v_file_name, 0);

   DBMS_XMLQuery.closecontext (ctx);
end;
/
```

Comment: Nice... and simpler! But should be `useNullAttributeIndicator` not `set...`; and might want to add a `setRowIDAttrName` call to be consistent with the `dbms_xmlgen` result? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5be7452be1326b766fedecbbd4fb7092)

Comment: Thank you and also DBMS_XMLGEN is faster. But look at this [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlque.htm#ARPLS69995)  the name of the procedure and the example are different. Sorry!

Comment: Oh yes... it's still wrong in the 19c docs. And feedback isn't working so can't report it *8-)

Comment: I am very new to pls/sql and xml target files. Your code seems to be working, but ```dbms_output.put_line(xmldoc);``` is not the right way I believe. After fetching the data, we need to post it to a path. Existing code is ```DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (xmldoc, 'target_path',  v_file_name,  0);``` 
How do I do this as well using DBMS_XMLQuery??

Comment: I noticed that the version number and encoding are in single quotes. Any way to represent them in double quotes? @davidm